Improving Nesting Efficiency/Scrap% Reduction in Sheet Metal (Laser Cutting)
I am currently working on a problem statement to improve the nesting efficiency and thereby reduce scrap generated for a sheet metal laser cutting setup (the nested parts are fairly complex/irregular in shape).
I am working on reducing the margin set for the machine and the spacing between the parts. But I think I might have reached my limit with a 5mm margin and a 3mm spacing. The sheets are 2000mm x 1500 mm on average if that's relevant.
Is there anything that can be done to improve the nesting efficiency or how packed the parts are?
Does anyone here work on Sigmanest/TruTops (Nesting Softwares) to give me a view on which of these softwares is better from this view point if that's the only thing that's there to improve efficiency further?
